# how can I get only the unread messages from gmail in android using imap?

Tags: android, gmail, imap

I'm using imap to connect to gmail and getting the whole inbox folder
where can i see if a specific mail is read/unread?

is there any way to fetch only the unread mails from the server instead of all the inbox folder?

thanks

Comment: offtopic question belongs on Android Exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer

```
FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);  
Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
```